# How to specify multiple labels for a Liquibase changeset?

Tags: liquibase

Liquibase supports labels for changesets and I would like to use them to differentiate between changesets only for the development and changesets for other environments.

The attibute name `labels` indicates, that I can use multiple labels (e.g. `envA` or `envB`) for the same changeset, but the documentation at https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/labels.html only shows how to use a single one.

How can I separate multiple labels? By space or comman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need to be separated by comma. From the docs:

> In your changelog, you can specify only a simple list of labels to apply to the changeset. For example, `labels="v.0.1, v.1.0"`.

Comment: I missed this part. To late, to much pressure. Thank you very much!